# Sangria left out overnight

Tags: storage, red-wine, cocktails

I made some sangria for a party - Spanish red, brandy, triple sec, peach schnapps, orange slices, lemon slices, strawberries, pineapple, generic tropical juice - and have accidentally left it out on the table while I was busy out dancing while under its influence. I know that as a rule, sangria that isn't on the table with some ice in it should be kept refrigerated, so my question is whether the leftovers are drinkable having been out for around 24 hours?

Comment: Put the bottle in the freezer for 24 hrs then dribble out the pure alcohol into a fresh sangria.
It will be muchos sangria

Comment: Was wondering same thing. I made one with moscato n vodka w crystal light lemonade n Sprite and added lemon n strawberries(not alot) with ice. It's been out for a few days n was wondering if good. I took fruit out tonight n ditched it but drinking it one ice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I had a sip of it out of curiosity, and it tasted great, so I finished off what was left. No ill health effects to report so it would appear it was fine! I will say that the fruit looked slightly worse for wear so I didn't eat any of it, but otherwise the drink was delicious.

Answer (score 4):

Grain alcohol (brandy, triple sec, peach schnapps) does not spoil while it's sitting in your liquor cabinet.  A bottle of wine, even with the oxidation after it's opened, can be drank for more or less 36 hours after opening (eventually it becomes vinegar).  The fruit would take time to decay, much longer than 24 hours.

Next time, eat the fruit.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already went ahead and finished off the Sangria, but in the future, I would probably recommend against it. Slicing the fruit exposes it to bacteria and between that and the juice you used it's always best to refrigerate perishable foods. I wouldn't be nearly as concerned as I would with leaving meat at room temperature, for example, but it always pays to be safe.

Comment: Alcohol kills bacteria through a process known as denaturation.  More info: https://sciencing.com/alcohol-kill-bacteria-5462404.html

Comment: Probably depends how boozy the sangria is, personally, mine would always be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the final alcoholic degree is a key point in matter of conservation. Knowing what, how much and with which alcoholic degree, of the different beverages you put in your sangria, you should be able to grossly evaluate this final degree (consider fruits like their volume of non-alcoholic juice).

Answer (score -1):

Well I left mine out for 3 days with oranges, apples, peaches, lemons, pineapple along with Stella Rosa peach wine, triple sec, Cpt. Morgan rum, Jim beam vanilla, Malibu rum, crystal lite lemonade, and drank it without getting sick. Just didn’t eat the fruit as it looked very ripe!